# Search record from DataGridView through two DateTimePicker in Windows Application Form Csharp 10?

Tags: c#

I have used the following code in Button and placed two DateTimePickers at the Windows Application Form for getting the specific record in the DataGridView having dates, but code not working.

```
private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        inwardTableAdapter.Fill(receiveIssueDataSet.Inward);

        string filterExpression = string.Format("Inward_Date >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND Inward_Date <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", dateTimePicker1.Value, dateTimePicker2.Value);
        inwardBindingSource.Filter = filterExpression;
        inwardDataGridView.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions, log, or display error messages
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```